# How to use google map in tabs with gmaps4rails 2.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails 2 + rails 4.0.0 + ruby 2.0 + Geocoder + twitter-bootstrap 3 + ajax_call

suppose i am creating a form with some details with address/location creation is working fine, data is saving to the database with latitude and longitude. => Fine

@view i can see the map too.

but when i am going for the updating that is ajax call simple i am refreshing the div that time google map is not coming.

same thing happen with #pop_up if i will use for updating latitude and longitude then also map is not comeing.

I guess gmap files are not loading or i have some problem with ajax call ? any solution????

**Controller's Action**

```
  def update_content
      @geo_hash = CommonUtils.get_gmap_hash(@seo_content) #getting latitude & longitude
    end
```

**update.js.erb**

```
$('.container-fluid').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'view_content', :seo_content => @seo_content) %>");
```

**view_content.html.erb**

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: { Zoom: 10 }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @geo_hash.to_json unless @geo_hash.blank? %>);
});
handler.map.centerOn({ lat: <%=raw @geo_hash[0][:lat] unless @geo_hash.blank? %>, lng: <%=raw @geo_hash[0][:lng] unless @geo_hash.blank? %> })
</script>
```

** Update is an ajax_call..
**application.js**

```
//= require gmaps_google
//= require markerclusterer_packed
//= require underscore
```

Comment: show your code. I personaly always use ajax so I can tell neither gem nor ajax are to blame

Comment: I am not blaming to gem or ajax.. i am just assuming only

Comment: you cant insert javascript the way you do it, neither the google script nor the handler calls. Please learn your basics

Comment: i added this files at application.js

Comment: //= require gmaps_google
//= require markerclusterer_packed
//= require underscore